# Liferay Angular default route not working

Tags: angular, liferay-7

I am using Liferay 7.x for creating an Angular 8 Portlet with multiple facets.
For registering the facets I am using RouterModule - excerpt below:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    { path: "new-customer", component: AddNewCustomerComponent },
    { path: "list-customers", component: CustomerListComponent },
    { path: "", redirectTo: "list-customers", pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "list-customers" }
  ],
  { useHash: true }
)
```

The issue is that by default, when I load the page containing the portlet, the default facet is not /#/list-customers. In fact, I had to add an anchor on which I manually click in order to load any facet.

So, the question is, how to make RouterModule in Liferay Angular Portlet work as expected.

Note: the same settings work in a standalone Angular project; also, the routes are setup correctly because I can navigate between them via link and manual clicks.

Comment: As a workaround I have added ngAfterViewInit(){} method and in it I have programatically switched to the "list-customers" view: this.router.navigate(["/list-customers"]);